# RefreshAll refreshes 4 PivotTables (same cache/source) but NOT last PivotTable (different cache/source)

Tags: excel, vba

my one worksheet has 5 PivotTables in total. ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll will oddly refresh 4 of the PivotTables that are using the same data source (assuming same cache), but it won't refresh the last PivotTable using a different data source.

Oddly I tried this PivotCache Refresh loop and followed by RefreshAll. This seems to fix it, but is there a bigger problem here? Odd that the RefreshAll function doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

If it matters, it's the Net2_PT that doesn't refresh.

Any advice is appreciated.

```
Sub Refresh_Data()

Call AddDataMods1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim pc As PivotCache **THIS FIXES THE ISSUE BUT SEEMS UNECESSARY...**
For Each pc In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
    pc.Refresh
Next pc

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

'Sort PivotTables largest to smallest

wsR1.PivotTables("Buy_PT").PivotFields("Top10").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Sum of Cash"

wsR1.PivotTables("Sell_PT").PivotFields("Top10").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Sum of Cash"
    
 wsR1.PivotTables("Net2_PT").PivotFields("Top10").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Sum of Net"
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Refresh Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the data source for the pivot that doesn't refresh?

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly an interesting bug. My best guess is that the data connect is set to not refresh on Refresh All. To check and fix this go to Data -> Queries & Connections -> Right click on the data source -> Properties -> Check the box. See the image below:

[image: Please excuse the sloppy paint editing]

Comment: Appreciate the reply, so i click the PivotTable, then go to Queries & Connections, but both tabs under Q/C show nothing, so there's nothing to right click on.

Comment: This is strange indeed. I poked around a bit but can't replicate your issue. Locking sheets or setting EnableRefresh to False will make RefreshAll skip the cache but they would also return an error when you did your work-around. Is all your data internal to this workbook or are you referencing any outside data?